# SpriteKit landscape orientation not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

everyone. I'm making an app with Xcode 9 and swift 4 with SpriteKit and I want the game to be in landscape mode.

I have tried setting in the project setting to allow only landscape and have added this code in the app delegate file.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    //make device portrait unless it is the game view controller
    if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is GameViewController {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape;

    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait;
    }
}
```

But neither of those work, the SpriteKit scene is still loaded in portrait. How do I make the scene load in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the info.plist in your project and at the bottom should be two elements, "Supported interface orientations", and "Supported interface orientations(iPad)". Click the drop down and remove the portrait mode orientations from both elements.

Comment: This hasn't worked the game scene is still loaded in portrait

Comment: is the scene loaded in portrait or is your scene size portrait but scaled weird